# Win Server Security: Why do members of a group not get access when the Group has permission?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, permissions, groups

Environment: No Active Directory and no Domain Controller.  Server is Win 2008

I have a directory with only ALLOW permissions set (no DENY permission)..and no inherited permissions.  I have two groups(Administrators and CoOwners) set to Full control.  However, the members of that group are not able to view/modify the folder.

If I explicitly add the 'Administrator' with full permissions, for example, then that user can access/modify fine.  Why isn't giving the GROUP permission giving the members of that group the access I would expect?

Any input/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you testing this over the network or from an interactive logon?

Comment: In your testing, I am guessing you added users to the CoOwners group?  Did you logout and login again?  Groups membership is only checked when the user first logs in / connects.

Comment: Login/logout from what?  Reboot the server(ugh) or the machine I'm trying to access from(Server or Win7 or XP)?

Comment: What are the permissions on the parent folders? Are these users or groups permitted to traverse the tree to reach the target?

Comment: Russ, can you post screenshots of your share permissions and NTFS permissions on the shared folder? (And regarding the comment by Zoredache, rebooting either the client OR server should do the trick.)

Comment: @Zoredache: Yes, I have logged out and logged in again to the server.  Note that I am doing this via RDC and not local.

@John: Well, all folders have full access to ADMINISTRATORS by default and I have confirmed this.

@Nic: For the screenshots, you would end up needing a few, right?  This folder, the parent folder, Administrators group, etc.  If this is required, I'll have to edit each screenshot to blur names, etc.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, I would say that group membership hasn't been established yet.

When you establish an SMB connection with a server, that's when the server determines which groups you are a part of. Changes to group membership won't take effect until the SMB connection is reset. Use the `whoami` tool to verify this.

```
> whoami /groups
```

You can get a list of open sessions using the Share and Storage Management administrative tool, and you can even close an SMB session right there, which makes testing much faster.

**Update:** It is usually a good idea to only assign permissions at the NTFS level. Try changing your share permissions to allow "Full Control" for "Everyone" to eliminate one possible cause.

Comment: When I run whoami /groups, it says my ID (I am logged in as 'Administrator') is in a bunch of groups including 'Administrators'.  What are you suggesting I try to verify I my credentials are correct?  thanks.

Comment: If you've set up the ACL on your shared folder so that "CoOwners" has full control, then you want to make sure that "CoOwners" also appears in `whoami`.

Answer (score -3):

Because in a GPO ( wheter have AD or not, windows O.S.s have GPOs ;) ) top-level permissions always overrides lover levels. And if there is no specific policy, the behaviour will be "Always Deny". In ths case when you explicitly add "Administrator" whis is a user, overrides the policy for "Administrators" which is a group and voila, you get your permissions. When you dont add, group policy grants that permission but default user permission ( for admin e.g ) overrides and denies it... BUT, when you give "Ownership"... This is what you need :) It always overrides defaults ;) ( and of course unless you explicitly add any user ;) as i mentioned above top-level policies ALWAYS overrides lover level policies ;) )

Comment: Less emoticons and more answer in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is incorrect. Not all operating systems have group policy; maybe you're thinking of ACLs? Top level permissions will apply to the descendents when inheritance is enabled, but they never "override" lower levels.

Comment: i was talking about windows operating systems.was i wrong?actually,yes,sorry,advanced security options came with ntfs and my assumption covers win2k and after.and by top-level,i must be wrote upside-down,i was mentioning not base but derived policies.like if a "group" policy is low-level,a "user" policy will be top-level (and this should be reversed if i'm wrong).so if there is no ownership and no specific permission,the policy will be defaultly 'deny' right?so this is my base (low level).and if i enter a user right (this is my top level) it overrides base and runs the actual user right,right?

Comment: I am using Win Server 2008.  I wonder if there is any conflict between 'Permissions' and 'Sharing options'.  Both are only trying to give access to the folder to Administrators and CoOwners.  Note that I am accessing the WinServer2008 shared folder from the WinServer2008 machine, a Win7 machine, and an XP machine.

Comment: Not a clear answer, though I do like the idea of "lover-level policies". @ErnieTheGeek, you mean "fewer emoticons", not "less emoticons". ;)

Comment: @hmallett: Too right, I do mean fewer, darn grammar nazi :P. @Russ: I generally configure the share permissions to give everyone full access and customize the NTFS permissions to restrict/allow access.

Comment: Hmm..that's an interesting point.  I have the share permissions only allowing access to the defined group...not 'everyone'.  Is this a common approach?  Setting all shares to everyone and control access via NTFS permissions?  My problem may lie in this area.